# Prevent number from being converted to Scientifc Notation in linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query that fetches data from the database. I have a DTO that contains a property `Price` of type `string`.

```
var query = (from Users in _db.Users 
join pricing in _db.Prices
select new {
Username = Users.Name,
Price = pricing.Currency + " " + pricing.Amount
} ).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new UsersPrice 
{

Username = x.Username,
Price = x.Price
});
```

Note that the `pricing.Amount` is of type double in my entity and the field in SQL server is float.

The real amount/ value in the database is `12 565 467` but in the above query its returning me as `1.25655e+007`. How can I prevent this ? I want the actual value that is in the database to be returned. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual value in the database **is a number**. Numbers do not include formatting - they are *just numbers*. The only time formatting is relevant is when you convert it to a string i.e.

```
Price = pricing.Currency + " " + pricing.Amount
```

So; if the format matters to you, you'll have to tell it what format you want **at that point**, typically by using `ToString()` specifying a specific format and culture.

To prevent the tool from trying to translate that to TSQL (which won't work), you might want to split the "get the data" part from the "format the data" part, i.e.

```cs
var query = (from Users in _db.Users 
join pricing in _db.Prices
select new {
    Username = Users.Name,
    pricing.Currency, pricing.Amount
}).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new UsersPrice 
{
    Username = x.Username,
    Price = x.Currency + " " + x.Amount.ToString(...) // your choices here
});
```

where the relevant bit here is that in the *ORM* query I've just selected the columns, and **after** the `AsEnumerable()` I have the code that *formats* them.

Comment: Thank you Mr Marc. Awesome !